# What is the best way to automate copy and paste specific ranges in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and there is a task I would like to automate and don't know where to start. I have a data set that looks like below.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxqFI.png)

What I'm trying to do is loop through column A and if it has something in it (will always be an email) select all rows until there is something in column A again. Copy and paste into new tab. So row 2-5 would copy and paste into a new tab. Then row 6-9 into a different new tab. Also row 1 would copy to each tab as well. I haven't been able to find code to help with this specific need and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I found this code and started modifying it but, it's nowhere close to what I need or working for that matter.

```
Sub split()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range

Set rng = Range("A:A")

For Each row In rng
    'test if cell is empty
    If row.Value <> "" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        row.Select
        row.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        row.PasteSpecial
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. *I haven't been able to find code to help with this specific need * - Please post the code that you **have** written to accomplish your goal. You will receive a lot more help and a lot faster by posting your efforts and where they are failing. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should provide what you need:

```
Sub Split()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) 'change sheet index or use Worksheets("Sheet1") method to use exact name

Dim rngBegin As Range
Dim rngEnd As Range

With ws

    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:H1") 'to copy headers over each time

    Dim lRowFinal As Long
    lRowFinal = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'assumes eventually last row of needed data will have an address1

    Set rngEnd = .Range("A1") ' to begin loop
    Set rngBegin = rngEnd.End(xlDown) 'to begin loop

    Do

        Set rngEnd = rngBegin.End(xlDown).Offset(-1)

        Dim wsNew As Worksheet
        Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(.Index))'always after current sheet, change as needed

        .Range(.Cells(rngBegin.Row, 1), .Cells(rngEnd.Row, 8)).Copy wsNew.Range("A2")
        wsNew.Range("A1:H1").Value = rngHeader.Value

        Set rngBegin = rngEnd.End(xlDown)

    Loop Until rngBegin.Row >= lRowFinal

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is what I needed to get started!

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your process into steps and determine rules on how to proceed.  Then write out some pseudo-code (code like logic) to make sure it all makes sense.

1. You need some sort of loop, since you are going to treat each
   group of rows in the same way.
2. You need some code that determines what cells are contained in each block
3. Code to take a block (given by step 2) and paste it into a new tab.

Your Pseudo Code might look like this:

```
' This is the main function that runs the whole routine
Sub Main()

Set headerRg = GetHeaderRg()
Do Until IsAtTheEnd(startRow) = True
    Set oneBlock = GetNextBlock(startRow)
    Call ProcessBlock(oneBlock)
    startRow = startRow + oneBlock.Rows.Count

Loop

End Sub

' This function returns the header range to insert into the top
Function GetHeaderRg() As Range
    ' Write some code here that returns the header range
End Function

' This function determines whether we are at the end of our data
Function IsAtTheEnd(current_row as Long) as Boolean
    ' Write some code here that determines whether we have hit the end of our data 
    '(probably checks the first column to see if there is data)
End Function

' This function takes the startRow of a block and returns the whole block of Rows
Function GetNextBlock(startRow) As Range
    ' Write some code that returns the whole range you want to copy
End Function    


' This sub takes a range to be processed and a header to print and prints 
' it into a new tab
Sub ProcessBlock(BlockRg As Range, headerRg as Range)
    Set targetSheet = thisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
    ' Write some code that pastes the headerRg and BlockRg where you want it
End Sub
```

If you start to have more specific questions about syntax etc, we will be happy to help here!