# excel close a specific worksheet

Tags: visual-foxpro, excel-automation

I writing a foxpro program that generate report from the excel. In the final process, there are two(2) excel generated by the program. I created a new workbook and copy the two output excel sheet into new workbook. How can I close the two excel file?

my code

```
**creating new workbook
XL = tmp.application
XL.workbooks.ADD()
XL.visible = .T.
XLsheet = XL.ActiveSheet

**opening the aging excel output
sheetdir=SYS(5)+SYS(2003)+"\temp\EXCEL1.xls"
XL.workbooks.OPEN(sheetdir)
XL.worksheets.COPY(XLsheet)
XL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Autofit
XL.ActiveSheet.name="P1"
xl.cells(1,1).value="xx"

XLsheet = XL.ActiveSheet
**opening the unvalidated excel output
sheetdir=SYS(5)+SYS(2003)+"\temp\EXCEL2.xls"
XL.workbooks.OPEN(sheetdir)
XL.worksheets.COPY(XLsheet)
XL.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Autofit
XL.ActiveSheet.name="P2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
#define xlNormal 39  && defines the version of Excel
oxl = createobject("Excel.Application")
oxl.Workbooks.add()
oBook = oxl.ActiveWorkbook()
oxl.visible = .f.
osheet = oxl.activesheet

 && update the worksheet

 oxl.DisplayAlerts = .f. && do not invoke any dialog 

 oBook.saveas(mfilex,xlNormal )
 && you can use oBook.Close() if you just want to close the book without saving

 oxl.quit()
 release oxl
```

Comment: But I need to currently open the consolidated excel. I was thinking if i can use the move excel sheet to my working workbook.

Comment: Try copy and paste:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996991/what-is-the-best-way-to-automate-copy-and-paste-specific-ranges-in-excel

Comment: You don't need copy&paste. There is Copy() method which you can use to Copy a sheet from another Workbook and/or Sheet.

Comment: I use the move() method and the other two workbook will close.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Close() method of Workbook.

PS: Please check your previous question(s) and close < g > them.